Use hash in remote module URL for webpack module federated components
I have a app that loads some module federated components. For example:
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'app',
      remotes: {
        remoteComponent1:'remoteComponent1@https://localhost:3000/remote.js',
        remoteComponent2:'remoteComponent2@https://localhost:3000/remote.js',
      },
      shared: {},
    }),
  ],

And in the remote components I am exposing the app like this:
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'remoteComponent1', 
      fileName: 'remote.js',
      exposes:{}
    }),
  ],
};

What I am trying to do is using some hash for the generated file for the remote components for example:
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'remoteComponent1', 
      fileName: 'remote.[contenthash].js',//so that the build will generate a unique file
      exposes:{}
    }),
  ],

But then, when I am trying to import that remote app in my host app using the contenthash, I am having trouble or don't know how can I acheive this since the contenthash can change everytime with the build: I tried this one but not able to make it work.
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'app',
      remotes: {
        remoteComponent1:`remoteComponent1@https://localhost:3000/remote.${[contenthash]}.js`,
        remoteComponent2:'remoteComponent2@https://localhost:3000/remote.js',
      },
      shared: {},
    }),
  ],


Did you find any solution for this?

Could't figure out a proper way to do it. But, somehow managed with dyamic remote module URL by adding a query parameter at the end of URL. This might be useful: https://github.com/module-federation/utilities/blob/main/runtime/importRemote/README.md
